# Google App Engine : Domain name stopped working

Tags: google-app-engine, domain-name

I recently got a domain name I'd bought through a third party to work with my GAE app.

A month ago, it was working fine. Now, however, when I try to use it I'm getting a message from GAE :

```
404. That’s an error.

The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

This message is the same for a number of different and valid paths. Eg.

```
The requested URL /admin was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

The app is still running and working fine through http://appname.appspot.com/ . Clearly the calls are finding their way to GAE, because that's what's giving me the 404. And, like I say, this was working a month ago.

What did I change in the meantime? Nothing. Or rather, I have now also migrated from the legacy store to the high replication store, but this problem appeared before I did that.

Anyone got an idea what I should be looking at to try to debug this?

*Note : this may seem off-topic for SO. However I'm asking it here because the GAE mailing group has a message telling me that this is now the official place to get GAE support.*

Answer (score 0):

OK. It looks like Google Apps deleted my account ... I presume because I hadn't verified that I owned the domain name within a 14 day limit. (Something that happened without them sending me any kind of warning email which I consider appalling un-service) So I had to go and recreate the Google Apps account all over again. :-(

This was **despite** that fact that the domain name was already working with my app. because I'd set up a correct CNAME record at my domain providers. I'd have thought they could have worked it out.

Or maybe they deleted the account because my free trial ran out? Do they want to charge me for Google Apps even if I'm only using it for a domain name for a GAE experiment?